# Why can selected users access website via IP but not URL?

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns, http-status-code-404, iis-8

I have ASP.NET 2.0 application which is hosted on a server with IIS 8.0 . The website was working fine, until some users reported a 404 error when they hit the URL. 
Now this happens only for a handful of users and they can access the website if they do it through the IP address.

I have tried flushing the DNS on their systems but with no luck.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

UPDATE: Some users have now complained about 400 error. This takes the total number of errored hits to 10.

Comment: Check the http status subcodes in the iis logs for the 404s and 400s, they may give you additional information on what's going on.

Comment: Yup.Will do that and update the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you can ping from pc that in not working by domain name and by ip number.

If it works only with ip then there is something with dns. You can try to use nslookup command on this pc to find more answers.

Some reason maybe not working pc is in some other network, maybe some firewall rule blocks it.

Comment: The the client system responds properly to ping from cmd. Even nslookup doesn't give any error on the machine. But trying to access the website via url gives 404 error.

Comment: ping ip_addres and ping domain_name, both are ok?

Comment: yes. Both working fine. UPDATE: Now some users have come up saying that they get 400 http status code error.

Comment: do you have some proxy server that maybe is caching data?

Comment: None that I'm aware of. Can a app pool refresh fix the issue. I cannot see why this would happen. And that too only for a certain number of users.

Comment: Is there some rule, patterns that matches all not working users? Some phisical location? or some other patern that matches all not woking users?